# Related question div - can't scroll in iP[ad|hone]

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, iphone, safari, ipad

When posting a question, after the title is entered a "Related Questions" div pushes the question body text box down and shows a scrolling window of questions related to the question title.

In most browsers and operating systems this is scrolling.

On the iPad and iPhone it is not.  The first 5 suggestions are visible, and a portion of the sixth, which, perhaps, may be sufficient, but it's annoying to not be able to review other question suggestions - it *looks* broken because of that incompletely visible sixth line.

I don't know what the root cause is, though, so I don't have a suggestions or reason why it doesn't work - perhaps it's due to the way these devices work with the touchscreen.

But would be nice if it were fixed, and if not at least hide the 6th suggestion so it looks as though it's supposed to be only five suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two fingers down on the list of questions and move your fingers up/down. You can now scroll. Works on almost any website with scrolling in divs

Comment: Works scrolling divs sideways too